# Set the text from various EditText to TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

I have created layout through code which consist of `LinearLayout` in which I have one `TextView` one `EditText` three `Buttons` namely add, remove and set respectively and a `TextView` when I click on add button new `EditText` is added in layout. When I click on remove button remove the `EditText`from layout and when I click on set button set the text from various edittext to `TextView`. I am unable to append the string from various `EditText` to `TextView`.

Here is my code

```
package com.example.rushikesh.assignment3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView textView;
EditText edt;
Button btnAdd, btnRemove,btnSet;
LinearLayout linearLayout;
EditText editText;
int count = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    edt = new EditText(this);
    edt.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


    btnAdd = new Button(this);
    btnAdd.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    btnAdd.setText("+");


    btnRemove = new Button(this);
    btnRemove.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    btnRemove.setText("-");

    btnSet = new Button(this);
    btnSet.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    btnSet.setText("SET");

    linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    linearLayout.addView(textView);
    linearLayout.addView(edt);
    linearLayout.addView(btnAdd);
    linearLayout.addView(btnRemove);
    linearLayout.addView(btnSet);

    setContentView(linearLayout);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            editText = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            editText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            linearLayout.addView(editText);
            count++;
        }
    });

    btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(count > 0)
            {
                linearLayout.removeViewAt(5);
                count--;

            }else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No edit text found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    btnSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

   }
}
```

Comment: Use a XML for the layout. Reusing the layoutParams object is completely wrong as each View must have their own corresponding LayoutParams. Using a XML for the layout takes care of all this for you, allowing to keep your main code clean.

Comment: I completely agree with you we must use XML to create layout. But the problem statement is like that we are told to create layout through code

Comment: @AkshayNaik You can do both things in the same time. You use an xml layout as template, you inflate it in java and you add it in any view you want. See `LayoutInflater.from(Context...).inflate(layout.xml, ..., ...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a reference to all the EditTexts in a List.

```
List<EditText> editTexts = ...

editTexts.add(editText);
```

And `onClick` of the `btnSet`, get the text from the `EditTexts` and set it to `TextView`.

```
String fullText;

for (EditText editText in editTexts) {
    fullText += editText.getText().toString();
}

textView.setText(fullText);
```